# Data extraction based on given criteria using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

EDIT: Thanks for the help before, I have made the changes in the code and edited my question (including some references like A & B) so that it's easier to understand now.

I have a multiple files in a folder with a lot of columns, lets call one these files "main.csv". There are 2 columns in "main" which contain X and Y coordinates. On another file called "site.csv", I have a list of the *required* X and Y coordinates and their **Site#**
I made a VBA to:

1)Keep in the "main" file, only the rows which match the X and Y coordinates in "B" AND also update a column called 'Site' in the main file with that in the "site.csv" file (screenshot attached)

2) Delete all the rest

***And if possible***  (Because I dont know how to code for this)
-> Make this VBA loop thru all the files (like"main.csv") in the folder as there are a LOT of them. The reference file is the same -"site.csv"

Screenshots:

[Main.csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXeNH.jpg)

[Site.csv file - Reference file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUfqh.jpg)

So far I'm getting the following error:

Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error (Location as VBA comment)

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub fetchdata()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim finalrow As Long
Dim i As Integer

Dim LastRow As Long

x = Application.Workbooks("Site.csv").Worksheets("Site").Range("A2").Value 'Stores the x-coordinate of the Site file which contains the list of required coordinates

y = Application.Workbooks("Site.csv").Worksheets("Site").Range("B2").Value

finalrow = Application.Workbooks("Main.csv").Worksheets("Main").Range("D70000").End(xlUp).Row 'Stores the row detail of the last row in the Main file

For i = 7 To finalrow
    If Application.Workbooks("Main.csv").Worksheets("Main").Range(Cells(i, 4) = x And Cells(i, 5) = y) Then 'ERROR IDENTIFIED HERE
        Application.Workbooks("Site.csv").Worksheets("Site").Range(Cells(i - 5, 3)).Copy
        Application.Workbooks("Main.csv").Worksheets("Main").Range("F7").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats 'Here I basically want to replace the existing site number with that in my reference file (site.csv)

    Else
        Application.Workbooks("Main.csv").Worksheets("Main").Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete 'Delete Everything else
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: qualify all objects to their parents. No where in the code do you specify which `workbook` you want to work with. Also `Cells(i,4)` should be qualified to a worksheet (and the worksheet to a workbook).

Comment: When working with different sheets and specially workbooks its best practice and also required that you be explicit with your objects. Try fixing them first. Examples are Workbooks("B").WorkSheets("B").Range("A7") or Workbooks("A").WorkSheets("A")

Comment: @ScottHoltzman  Made changes, please take a look

Comment: @fcsr Thanks for the input, made the changes

Comment: are you still getting an error?

Comment: on the line with the error, edit the second arguement `And Cells(i, 5) = y) Then` , also add the Application.Workbooks("Main.csv").Worksheets("Main"). Complete the object and try again

Comment: @fcsr I edited it but still getting the error If Application.Workbooks("Main.csv").Worksheets("Main").Range(Cells(i, 4) = x) And Application.Workbooks("Main.csv").Worksheets("Main").Range(Cells(i, 5) = y) Then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi your errors are in these lines:

`.Range(Cells(i, 4)       I removed Range()`

`= y)       I removed ")"`

`Range(Cells(i - 5, 3))     I removed Range()`

Below code should work

```
Option Explicit

Sub fetchdata()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim finalrow As Long
Dim i As Integer

Dim LastRow As Long

x = Application.Workbooks("Site.csv").Worksheets("Site").Range("A2").Value 'Stores the x-coordinate of the Site file which contains the list of required coordinates

y = Application.Workbooks("Site.csv").Worksheets("Site").Range("B2").Value

finalrow = Application.Workbooks("Main.csv").Worksheets("Main").Range("D70000").End(xlUp).Row 'Stores the row detail of the last row in the Main file

For i = 7 To finalrow
    If Application.Workbooks("Main.csv").Worksheets("Main").Cells(i, 4) = x And Cells(i, 5) = y Then 'ERROR IDENTIFIED HERE
        Application.Workbooks("Site.csv").Worksheets("Site").Cells(i - 5, 3).Copy
        Application.Workbooks("Main.csv").Worksheets("Main").Range("F7").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats 'Here I basically want to replace the existing site number with that in my reference file (site.csv)

    Else
        Application.Workbooks("Main.csv").Worksheets("Main").Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete 'Delete Everything else
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

**New code as of 08/12 with directory loop:**

```
Sub fetchdata()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim finalrow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim site As Workbook
Dim main As Workbook
Dim site_sh As Worksheet
Dim main_sh As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim finalrow_main, finalrow_site, i_site, i_main, site_val_x, site_val_y, main_val_x, main_val_y As Variant
Dim criteria As String
Dim delete_row As Boolean
Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
Dim file_path, list_file, final_message As String


file_path = "C:\Users\u6042371\Documents" 'Set directory for "Main" file types here

If Right(file_path, 1) <> "\" Then file_path = file_path & "\"

list_file = "" 'this will store a file list for later

criteria = "main*.xls" 'this will search for all files beginning with main ending with .xls, you can use * as a wildcard, just change main

file = Dir(file_path & criteria)

While (file <> "")

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=file_path & file

    Set main = Workbooks(file) 'will auto open
    Set site = Workbooks("Site.xlsx") 'manual open this workbook
    Set main_sh = main.Worksheets("Main") 'name of sheet ex Main sheet in Main workbook
    Set site_sh = site.Worksheets("Site") 'name of sheet ex Site sheet in Site workbook

    finalrow_main = main_sh.Range("D70000").End(xlUp).Row 'gets last row of Main Sheet
    finalrow_site = site_sh.Range("A70000").End(xlUp).Row 'gets last row of Site Sheet
    delete_row = False 'flag if to delete row at the end of for loop

    For i_main = finalrow_main To 7 Step -1 'to loop through all Main x, y, this looks through end to start of data, delete technique
        main_val_x = main_sh.Cells(i_main, 4).Value 'set x value of current row of Main sheet
        main_val_y = main_sh.Cells(i_main, 5) 'set y value of current row of Main sheet


        For i_site = 2 To finalrow_site 'to loop through all Site x,y starts at the beginning of site
            site_val_x = site_sh.Cells(i_site, 1) 'set x value of current row of Site sheet
            site_val_y = site_sh.Cells(i_site, 2) 'set y value of current row of Site sheet


            If site_val_x = main_val_x And site_val_y = main_val_y Then 'compares x,y from Site to x,y from Main
                main_sh.Cells(i_main, 6) = site_sh.Cells(i_site, 3)

                delete_row = False 'Set delete to false because there has been a match
                Exit For 'Exits loop to check next site row
            Else
                delete_row = True 'if there are no matches this will become True

            End If

        Next i_site

        If delete_row = True Then 'if delete = True then delete
            main_sh.Rows(i_main).Delete
        End If



    Next i_main

    Workbooks(file).Save
    Workbooks(file).Close
    list_file = list_file + file + Chr(13)

    file = Dir


Wend

final_message = "The following files have been processed:" + Chr(13) + list_file
MsgBox final_message

End Sub
```

Comment: It ran without errors but there wasn't any change reflected on the files. They seem to be the same.

Comment: Application.Workbooks("Main.csv").Worksheets("Main").Range("F7") this line is not dynamic, the code will paste on this cell everytime

Comment: I only tried to answer your existing question about the error, and I didnt really go through the entire logic of the code

Comment: youve made it more complicated than it originally was, you should think about the naming conventions of the files you will use, if main will be one file and there will be multiple site files. there are ways in vba to loop through file using wildcards, so all file with site will get processed. but will you have multiple main and site files in different folders? how will you associate main files to site files etc. I can help you but you need to be even more specific, as hard that it may sound

Comment: I'm sorry about the complication but such is the task that I'm trying to accomplish. So, there is one "Site" file and multiple "main" files.

Comment: Also, the name 'main' is just a sample; the files are usually named as part numbers (alphanumerics eg.1531-1700829PXQW). So "site" is a fixed name and a single file (mostly just acting as a reference) and 'main' is the file which will be changed. But the name 'main' is just an example, there are lots of files like 'main'(similar content) but their file name is a part number.

Comment: please try new code, this is just a trial or proof of concept, this is a very basic and repetitive code, this can be much elegant and simple but for testing this will do. try it by opening main and site, then paste this macro in a new workbook module

Comment: Works like an absolute charm. Thanks! Is there a way to automate this process for every file (like "main") in a directory?

Comment: there is actually, but i wanted you to try it out first on one file. I'll update my answer with the loop

Comment: The code is working but I'm not able to get the auto save and close function working. I Tweaked the code a bit in this line : Set main_sh = main.ActiveSheet 'name of sheet ex Main sheet in Main workbook

Comment: There is no error. But as the code runs, each <main> file is opened and the save dialog box is displayed. So I have to manually select save for each file. I know that the ActiveWorkbook.Save and ActiveWorkbook.Close functions are supposed to prevent this from happening but for some reason they don't seem to take effect.   But the code in general works perfect.

Comment: Are the main files ready only? Or are they a different file format than excel format? Like csv is a different format

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a method in the Range class called .ClearData. Did you mean [ClearContents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-clearcontents-method-excel)? This will clear all values from the specified cells.

```
Sub fetchdata()
    Dim x As Integer 'Coordinates that need to be fetched
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim finalrow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D10000").ClearContents
    x = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value
    y = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value
    finalrow = Sheets("Book1").Range("D10000").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 7 To finalrow
        If Cells(i, 4) = x And Cells(i, 5) = y Then
            Sheets("Book1").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 221)).Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        End If
    Next i
 End Sub
```